# Training spaCy model as a Vertex AI Pipeline "Component"

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, spacy-3, google-cloud-vertex-ai, spacy-transformers

I am trying to [train a spaCy model](https://spacy.io/usage/training) , but turning the code into a Vertex AI Pipeline [Component](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/vertex-pipelines-intro?hl=en#:%7E:text=Step%201%3A%20Create%20a%20Python%20function%20based%20component). My current code is:

```py
@component(
    packages_to_install=[
        "setuptools",
        "wheel", 
        "spacy[cuda113,transformers,lookups]",
    ],
    base_image="gcr.io/deeplearning-platform-release/base-cu113",
    output_component_file="train.yaml"
)
def train(train_name: str, dev_name: str) -> NamedTuple("output", [("model_path", str)]):
    """
    Trains a spacy model
    
    Parameters:
    ----------
    train_name : Name of the spaCy "train" set, used for model training.
    dev_name: Name of the spaCy "dev" set, , used for model training.
    
    Returns:
    -------
    output : Destination path of the saved model.
    """
    import spacy
    import subprocess
    
    spacy.require_gpu()  # <=== IMAGE FAILS TO BE COMPILED HERE
    
    # NOTE: The remaining code has already been tested and proven to be functional.
    #       It has been edited since the project is private.
    
    # Presets for training
    subprocess.run(["python", "-m", "spacy", "init", "fill-config", "gcs/secret_path_to_config/base_config.cfg", "config.cfg"])

    # Training model
    location = "gcs/secret_model_destination_path/TestModel"
    subprocess.run(["python", "-m", "spacy", "train", "config.cfg",
                    "--output", location,
                    "--paths.train", "gcs/secret_bucket/secret_path/{}.spacy".format(train_name),
                    "--paths.dev", "gcs/secret_bucket/secret_path/{}.spacy".format(dev_name),
                    "--gpu-id", "0"])
    
    return (location,)
```

The Vertex AI Logs display the following as main cause of the failure:

[image]

The libraries are successfully installed, and yet I feel like there is some missing library / setting (as I know by [experience](https://dev.to/davidgerva/spacy-3-on-a-google-cloud-compute-instance-to-train-a-ner-transformer-model-23hf)); however I don't know  how to make it "Python-based Vertex AI Components Compatible". BTW, the use of GPU is **mandatory** in my code.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some rehearsals, I think I have figured out what my code was missing. Actually, the `train` component definition was correct (with some minor tweaks relative to what was originally posted); however **the pipeline was missing the GPU definition**. I will first include a dummy example code, which trains a NER model using spaCy, and orchestrates everything via Vertex AI Pipeline:

```py
from kfp.v2 import compiler
from kfp.v2.dsl import pipeline, component, Dataset, Input, Output, OutputPath, InputPath
from datetime import datetime
from google.cloud import aiplatform
from typing import NamedTuple


# Component definition

@component(
    packages_to_install=[
        "setuptools",
        "wheel", 
        "spacy[cuda113,transformers,lookups]",
    ],
    base_image="gcr.io/deeplearning-platform-release/base-cu113",
    output_component_file="generate.yaml"
)
def generate_spacy_file(train_path: OutputPath(), dev_path: OutputPath()):
    """
    Generates a small, dummy 'train.spacy' & 'dev.spacy' file
    
    Returns:
    -------
    train_path : Relative location in GCS, for the "train.spacy" file.
    dev_path: Relative location in GCS, for the "dev.spacy" file.
    """
    import spacy
    from spacy.training import Example
    from spacy.tokens import DocBin

    td = [    # Train (dummy) dataset, in 'spacy V2 presentation'
              ("Walmart is a leading e-commerce company", {"entities": [(0, 7, "ORG")]}),
              ("I reached Chennai yesterday.", {"entities": [(19, 28, "GPE")]}),
              ("I recently ordered a book from Amazon", {"entities": [(24,32, "ORG")]}),
              ("I was driving a BMW", {"entities": [(16,19, "PRODUCT")]}),
              ("I ordered this from ShopClues", {"entities": [(20,29, "ORG")]}),
              ("Fridge can be ordered in Amazon ", {"entities": [(0,6, "PRODUCT")]}),
              ("I bought a new Washer", {"entities": [(16,22, "PRODUCT")]}),
              ("I bought a old table", {"entities": [(16,21, "PRODUCT")]}),
              ("I bought a fancy dress", {"entities": [(18,23, "PRODUCT")]}),
              ("I rented a camera", {"entities": [(12,18, "PRODUCT")]}),
              ("I rented a tent for our trip", {"entities": [(12,16, "PRODUCT")]}),
              ("I rented a screwdriver from our neighbour", {"entities": [(12,22, "PRODUCT")]}),
              ("I repaired my computer", {"entities": [(15,23, "PRODUCT")]}),
              ("I got my clock fixed", {"entities": [(16,21, "PRODUCT")]}),
              ("I got my truck fixed", {"entities": [(16,21, "PRODUCT")]}),
    ]
    
    dd = [    # Development (dummy) dataset (CV), in 'spacy V2 presentation'
              ("Flipkart started it's journey from zero", {"entities": [(0,8, "ORG")]}),
              ("I recently ordered from Max", {"entities": [(24,27, "ORG")]}),
              ("Flipkart is recognized as leader in market",{"entities": [(0,8, "ORG")]}),
              ("I recently ordered from Swiggy", {"entities": [(24,29, "ORG")]})
    ]

    
    # Converting Train & Development datasets, from 'spaCy V2' to 'spaCy V3'
    nlp = spacy.blank("en")
    db_train = DocBin()
    db_dev = DocBin()

    for text, annotations in td:
        example = Example.from_dict(nlp.make_doc(text), annotations)
        db_train.add(example.reference)
        
    for text, annotations in dd:
        example = Example.from_dict(nlp.make_doc(text), annotations)
        db_dev.add(example.reference)
    
    db_train.to_disk(train_path + ".spacy")  # <== Obtaining and storing "train.spacy"
    db_dev.to_disk(dev_path + ".spacy")      # <== Obtaining and storing "dev.spacy"
    

# ----------------------- ORIGINALLY POSTED CODE -----------------------

@component(
    packages_to_install=[
        "setuptools",
        "wheel", 
        "spacy[cuda113,transformers,lookups]",
    ],
    base_image="gcr.io/deeplearning-platform-release/base-cu113",
    output_component_file="train.yaml"
)
def train(train_path: InputPath(), dev_path: InputPath(), output_path: OutputPath()):
    """
    Trains a spacy model
    
    Parameters:
    ----------
    train_path : Relative location in GCS, for the "train.spacy" file.
    dev_path: Relative location in GCS, for the "dev.spacy" file.
    
    Returns:
    -------
    output : Destination path of the saved model.
    """
    import spacy
    import subprocess
    
    spacy.require_gpu()  # <=== IMAGE NOW MANAGES TO GET BUILT!

    # Presets for training
    subprocess.run(["python", "-m", "spacy", "init", "fill-config", "gcs/secret_path_to_config/base_config.cfg", "config.cfg"])

    # Training model
    subprocess.run(["python", "-m", "spacy", "train", "config.cfg",
                    "--output", output_path,
                    "--paths.train", "{}.spacy".format(train_path),
                    "--paths.dev", "{}.spacy".format(dev_path),
                    "--gpu-id", "0"])

# ----------------------------------------------------------------------
    

# Pipeline definition

@pipeline(
    pipeline_root=PIPELINE_ROOT,
    name="spacy-dummy-pipeline",
)
def spacy_pipeline():
    """
    Builds a custom pipeline
    """
    # Generating dummy "train.spacy" + "dev.spacy"
    train_dev_sets = generate_spacy_file()
    # With the output of the previous component, train a spaCy modeL    
    model = train(
        train_dev_sets.outputs["train_path"],
        train_dev_sets.outputs["dev_path"]
    
    # ------ !!! THIS SECTION DOES THE TRICK !!! ------
    ).add_node_selector_constraint(
        label_name="cloud.google.com/gke-accelerator",
        value="NVIDIA_TESLA_T4"
    ).set_gpu_limit(1).set_memory_limit('32G')
    # -------------------------------------------------

# Pipeline compilation   

compiler.Compiler().compile(
    pipeline_func=spacy_pipeline, package_path="pipeline_spacy_job.json"
)


# Pipeline run

TIMESTAMP = datetime.now().strftime("%Y%m%d%H%M%S")

run = aiplatform.PipelineJob(  # Include your own naming here
    display_name="spacy-dummy-pipeline",
    template_path="pipeline_spacy_job.json",
    job_id="ml-pipeline-spacydummy-small-{0}".format(TIMESTAMP),
    parameter_values={},
    enable_caching=True,
)


# Pipeline gets submitted

run.submit()
```

Now, the explanation; according to [Google](https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/docs/pipelines/machine-types):

> By default, the component will run on as a Vertex AI CustomJob using an e2-standard-4 machine, with 4 core CPUs and 16GB memory.

Therefore, when the `train` component gets compiled, it fails as "*it was not seeing any GPU available as resource*"; in the same link however, all the available settings for both CPU and GPU are mentioned. In my case as you can see, I set `train` component to run under ONE (1) `NVIDIA_TESLA_T4` GPU card, and I also increased my CPU memory, to 32GB. With these modifications, the resulting pipeline looks as follows:

[image]

And as you can see, it gets compiled successfully, as well as trains (and eventually obtains) a functional spaCy model. From here, you can tweak this code, to fit your own needs.

I hope this helps to anyone who might be interested.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the line that is failing. ie. `spacy.require_gpu()  # <=== IMAGE FAILS TO BE COMPILED HERE`

Also tweak to remove the cuda install line `cuda113,`

Your code is set to use a GPU, but for a learning exercise you don't need a GPU.   I don't know and you don't know how to specify a GPU enabled python vertex AI gcp instance.  Consequently remove the requirement for GPU.  Once you get the code running, you can go back and tweak to add the GPU.

Comment: Well, actually, I need the line "spacy.require_gpu()" as it is a spaCy requirement to train a model that uses transformers (which BTW my code does, in general terms). If you remove it, you will get an error, and spaCy will literally tell you to add that line before training the model (as I have just tested, by removing it). Therefore, that line needs to remain.

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo apt-key adv --fetch-keys https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/debian10/x86_64/7fa2af80.pub
sudo add-apt-repository "deb https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/debian10/x86_64/ /"
sudo add-apt-repository contrib
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get -y install cuda-11-2
python -m spacy download en_core_web_trf # optional
```

install other pip packages and dependencies on another cell `pip install torch==1.7.1+cu110 torchvision==0.8.2+cu110 torchaudio==0.7.2 -f https://download.pytorch.org/whl/torch_stable.html`

point to the correct cuda folder `export CUDA_PATH="/usr/local/cuda-11"`

install spacy transformers info `pip install -U spacy[cuda113,transformers]`
here more [info:](https://docs.cupy.dev/en/stable/install.html#installing-cupy) `pip install cupy-cuda113`

Now libraries and packets and cells are located and installed correctly this should work

```
>>> import spacy
>>> spacy.require_gpu()
```

Comment: Hello. Thanks for your input, however I see that most of these suggestions are (more or less) the same than the ones provided in the link of the last paragraph, of my original post. It would be more helpful to know "how can I include those CLI commands, so they can be installed in the 'packages_to_install' argument", in the "train" @component (line 2 of the code). I will try to include them "as they are" first, and see what happens.

Comment: Good answer elhe-blaster.  David, if you using a jupyter notebook you can modify the cell to be a bash cell with %%bash and then do the installs as suggested.