# Vertex AI Pipeline with Custom spaCy NER, Error: model server never became ready

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-vertex-ai, spacy-3

I created a Vertex AI Pipeline [some time ago](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72035340/16706763), and now I am working in adding another pipeline component, `predict`, to deploy the spaCy model I created with the first two blocks. The code I used was:

```py
from kfp.v2 import compiler
from kfp.v2.dsl import pipeline, component, Dataset, Input, Output, OutputPath, InputPath, Model, Artifact
from datetime import datetime
from google.cloud import aiplatform
from typing import NamedTuple

# Constant definition
REGION="us-central1"
PROJECT_ID="my-project"  # Project edited for safety purposes

# Set bucket name
BUCKET_NAME="gs://vertex-tests"

# Create bucket
PIPELINE_ROOT = f"{BUCKET_NAME}/pipeline_root/"
PIPELINE_ROOT

USER_FLAG = "--user"


# Component definition

@component(
    base_image="python:3.9",
    packages_to_install=[
        "setuptools",
        "wheel",
        "spacy==3.2.1",
    ],
    output_component_file="generate.yaml"
)
def generate_spacy_file(train_path: OutputPath(), dev_path: OutputPath()):
    """
    Generates a small, dummy 'train.spacy' & 'dev.spacy' file
    
    Returns:
    -------
    train_path : Relative location in GCS, for the "train.spacy" file.
    dev_path: Relative location in GCS, for the "dev.spacy" file.
    """
    import spacy
    from spacy.training import Example
    from spacy.tokens import DocBin

    td = [    # Train (dummy) dataset, in 'spacy V2 presentation'
              ("Walmart is a leading e-commerce company", {"entities": [(0, 7, "ORG")]}),
              ("I reached Chennai yesterday.", {"entities": [(19, 28, "GPE")]}),
              ("I recently ordered a book from Amazon", {"entities": [(24,32, "ORG")]}),
              ("I was driving a BMW", {"entities": [(16,19, "PRODUCT")]}),
              ("I ordered this from ShopClues", {"entities": [(20,29, "ORG")]}),
              ("Fridge can be ordered in Amazon ", {"entities": [(0,6, "PRODUCT")]}),
              ("I bought a new Washer", {"entities": [(16,22, "PRODUCT")]}),
              ("I bought a old table", {"entities": [(16,21, "PRODUCT")]}),
              ("I bought a fancy dress", {"entities": [(18,23, "PRODUCT")]}),
              ("I rented a camera", {"entities": [(12,18, "PRODUCT")]}),
              ("I rented a tent for our trip", {"entities": [(12,16, "PRODUCT")]}),
              ("I rented a screwdriver from our neighbour", {"entities": [(12,22, "PRODUCT")]}),
              ("I repaired my computer", {"entities": [(15,23, "PRODUCT")]}),
              ("I got my clock fixed", {"entities": [(16,21, "PRODUCT")]}),
              ("I got my truck fixed", {"entities": [(16,21, "PRODUCT")]}),
    ]
    
    dd = [    # Development (dummy) dataset (CV), in 'spacy V2 presentation'
              ("Flipkart started it's journey from zero", {"entities": [(0,8, "ORG")]}),
              ("I recently ordered from Max", {"entities": [(24,27, "ORG")]}),
              ("Flipkart is recognized as leader in market",{"entities": [(0,8, "ORG")]}),
              ("I recently ordered from Swiggy", {"entities": [(24,29, "ORG")]})
    ]

    
    # Converting Train & Development datasets, from 'spaCy V2' to 'spaCy V3'
    nlp = spacy.blank("en")
    db_train = DocBin()
    db_dev = DocBin()

    for text, annotations in td:
        example = Example.from_dict(nlp.make_doc(text), annotations)
        db_train.add(example.reference)
        
    for text, annotations in dd:
        example = Example.from_dict(nlp.make_doc(text), annotations)
        db_dev.add(example.reference)
    
    db_train.to_disk(train_path + ".spacy")  # <== Obtaining and storing "train.spacy"
    db_dev.to_disk(dev_path + ".spacy")      # <== Obtaining and storing "dev.spacy"
    

@component(
    base_image="gcr.io/deeplearning-platform-release/base-cu113",
    packages_to_install=[
        "setuptools",
        "wheel",
        "spacy==3.2.1",
        "spacy[cuda113,transformers,lookups]",
    ],
    output_component_file="train.yaml"
)
def train(train_path: InputPath(), dev_path: InputPath(), output_path: OutputPath()):
    """
    Trains a spacy model
    
    Parameters:
    ----------
    train_path : Relative location in GCS, for the "train.spacy" file.
    dev_path: Relative location in GCS, for the "dev.spacy" file.
    
    Returns:
    -------
    output : Destination path of the saved model.
    """
    import spacy
    import subprocess
    
    spacy.require_gpu()

    # Presets for training (Path edited for safety purposes)
    subprocess.run(["python", "-m", "spacy", "init", "fill-config", "gcs/ml-data/test_spacy/base_config.cfg", "config.cfg"])

    # Training model
    subprocess.run(["python", "-m", "spacy", "train", "config.cfg",
                    "--output", output_path,
                    "--paths.train", "{}.spacy".format(train_path),
                    "--paths.dev", "{}.spacy".format(dev_path),
                    "--gpu-id", "0"])


@component(
    base_image="python:3.9",
    packages_to_install=[
        "google-cloud-aiplatform",
        "setuptools",
        "wheel", 
        "spacy==3.2.1",
    ],
    output_component_file="predict.yaml"
)
def predict(
    model_path: InputPath(),
    project: str,
    region: str,
    serving_container_image_uri : str, 
    vertex_endpoint: Output[Artifact],
    vertex_model: Output[Model]
):
    
    from google.cloud import aiplatform
    aiplatform.init(project=project, location=region)

    DISPLAY_NAME  = "spacypredictor"
    MODEL_NAME = "spacypredictor-trf"
    ENDPOINT_NAME = "spacypredictor_endpoint"
    
    def create_endpoint():
        endpoints = aiplatform.Endpoint.list(
            filter='display_name="{}"'.format(ENDPOINT_NAME),
            order_by='create_time desc',
            project=project, 
            location=region,
        )
        if len(endpoints) > 0:
            endpoint = endpoints[0]  # most recently created
        else:
            endpoint = aiplatform.Endpoint.create(
                display_name=ENDPOINT_NAME, project=project, location=region
            )
    
    endpoint = create_endpoint()
    
    #Import a model programmatically
    model_upload = aiplatform.Model.upload(
        display_name = DISPLAY_NAME, 
        artifact_uri = model_path,
        serving_container_image_uri = serving_container_image_uri,
        # serving_container_health_route = f"/v1/models/{MODEL_NAME}",
        # serving_container_predict_route = f"/v1/models/{MODEL_NAME}:predict",
        serving_container_environment_variables = {
            "MODEL_NAME": MODEL_NAME,
        },       
    )

    # --- WHEN THIS CODE IS ENABLED, PIPELINE DOES NOT FINISH DEPLOYING ---

    # Deploy model to be used
    model_deploy = model_upload.deploy(
        machine_type="n1-standard-4",
        accelerator_type="NVIDIA_TESLA_T4",
        accelerator_count=1,
        endpoint=endpoint,
        traffic_split={"0": 100},
        deployed_model_display_name=DISPLAY_NAME,
    )

    # Save data to the output params
    vertex_model.uri = model_deploy.resource_name
    
    # ---------------------------------------------------------------------

# Pipeline definition

TIMESTAMP =datetime.now().strftime("%Y%m%d%H%M%S")
DISPLAY_NAME = 'pipeline-spacytest-job{}'.format(TIMESTAMP)

@pipeline(
    pipeline_root=PIPELINE_ROOT,
    name="spacy-dummy-pipeline",
)
# `serving_container_image_uri` edited for safety purposes
def spacy_pipeline(
    project: str = PROJECT_ID,
    region: str = REGION, 
    display_name: str = DISPLAY_NAME,
    api_endpoint: str = REGION+"-aiplatform.googleapis.com",
    serving_container_image_uri: str = "us-central1-docker.pkg.dev/my-project/skill-extractor-spacy-custom-container-prediction-sdk/skill-extractor-spacy-cpr-server-sdk"  # This container DO exist in Artifact Registry
):
    """
    Builds a custom pipeline
    """
    # Generating dummy "train.spacy" + "dev.spacy"
    train_dev_sets = generate_spacy_file()
    
    # With the output of the previous component, train a spaCy modeL    
    model = train(
        train_dev_sets.outputs["train_path"],
        train_dev_sets.outputs["dev_path"]
    ).add_node_selector_constraint(
        label_name="cloud.google.com/gke-accelerator",
        value="NVIDIA_TESLA_T4"
    ).set_gpu_limit(1).set_memory_limit('32G')
    
    # Serve previous model
    model_ep = predict(
        model.output,
        PROJECT_ID,
        REGION,
        serving_container_image_uri
    )


# Pipeline compilation   

compiler.Compiler().compile(
    pipeline_func=spacy_pipeline, package_path="pipeline_spacy_job.json"
)


# Pipeline run

TIMESTAMP = datetime.now().strftime("%Y%m%d%H%M%S")

run = aiplatform.PipelineJob(  # Include your own naming here
    display_name="spacy-dummy-pipeline",
    template_path="pipeline_spacy_job.json",
    job_id="ml-pipeline-spacydummy-small-{0}".format(TIMESTAMP),
    parameter_values={},
    enable_caching=False,  # Change to `True` for faster testing
)


# Pipeline gets submitted

run.submit()
```

Now please address your attention to the `predict` component: If the variables `model_deploy` and `vertex_model.uri` are *"taken out"* of the code, the pipeline gets successfuly built (In less than ~10 minutes); however if these variables are attempted to get declared, the pipeline compiles in a *considerable* ammount of time (i.e., ~1.5H), but **fails** to successfully deploy the endpoint and build a working pipeline, with the error (project number's first 4 digits have been edited with 'X' for safety purposes):

`google.api_core.exceptions.FailedPrecondition: 400 Error: model server never became ready. Please validate that your model file or container configuration are valid. Model server logs can be found at https://console.cloud.google.com/logs/viewer?project=XXXX64177482&resource=aiplatform.googleapis.com%252FEndpoint&advancedFilter=resource.type%3D%22aiplatform.googleapis.com%2FEndpoint%22%0Aresource.labels.endpoint_id%3D%22814874455623860224%22%0Aresource.labels.location%3D%22us-central1%22.`

Which is weird, as the code used was taken and slightly modified from the original Google documentation, for both the [model importation](https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/docs/model-registry/import-model#import_a_model_programmatically), as well as the [endpoint construction](https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/docs/predictions/get-predictions#send_an_online_prediction_request).

What could be possibly going on here?

ADDENDA:

I will include some notes & updates in this section, either from my side, as well as further details requested in the comment section below.

NOTE 1: The artifact pointed by `serving_container_image_uri` parameter, in the `spacy_pipeline` definition, was built and deployed using [this](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/vertex-ai-samples/blob/main/notebooks/community/prediction/custom_prediction_routines/SDK_Custom_Predict_SDK_Integration.ipynb) code as reference (adapting it to a spaCy model). I have decided to leave it out, as the individual tests worked OK an in general, this is a Docker container, and so a *"Black Box"* . If this is somehow important, let me know and I'll figure out a way to include that here.

Comment: It is possible it missed the container requirement check here: https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/docs/predictions/custom-container-requirements. Also it might be a back end issue if it does not show any logs for this process, I would recommend to file an issue here: https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers

Comment: @NestorCenizaJr, the pipeline managed to compile and complete, however triggering a new error. I have updated the issue description. I think I will open a New Google Support Case Ticket, and refer this case there (while also adding the full, 
unpublished code). Anyways, if you identify something in this code, let me know. Thank you.